# Are there chemical elements deadly to mushrooms but not to humans?

Tags: science-based, biology, environment, chemistry

Are there any chemical elements dangerous to fungus/mushrooms that wouldn't threaten the human species.

The chemical elements I'm looking for would be in the periodic table of elements.

It doesn't matter if the element kills the fungus/mushroom instantly or slowly, so long as it is not a threat to us humans.

Comment: The poison is in the dose, as they say. Any element in sufficient quantity to kill a mushroom would probably not affect a human of several hundred times greater mass

Comment: Chemical elements as such are quite rare in nature; they are usually found bound in compounds, which have vastly different chemical properties that the constituent elements. (For example, sodium is a metal which self-ignites in contact with water, chlorine is a deadly asphyxiating gas, but sodium chloride is table salt.) How do you intend to deliver the chemical element in question? As a gas, in solution, ground to fine dust? You do understand that a "mushroom" is the fruiting body of a fungus, and the fungus itself is most usually underground and much larger than the mushroom?

Comment: Yeah, i know about the fungus AlexP, and i don't have any restriction about how to deliver the chemical element in question.

Comment: Do you really need an element rather than just using a fungicide?

Answer (score 4):

Nitrogen is in fertilizer and helps deter mushroom growth by lessening the lifespan of the mushroom. There are things that help that aren't directly on the Periodic Table. While grass and some flowering plants thrive in a lower PH level soil, mushrooms prefer high PH levels and will not grow well or produce fruit in acidic soils. While lime will not actually kill the mushrooms, it can work to slow and eliminate the fungus when used in conjunction with other lawn chemicals. Acidic elements can be used: aluminum oxides are amphoteric (reacting both as a base or acid), while silicon, phosphorus, sulfur and chlorine oxides are acidic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helps a lot, and for you which acidic elements is the "best" one ?

Comment: @Rowyn Alloway Your chemistry is totally wrong: "Mushrooms prefer lower PH levels..... will not grow well in acidic soils" - Low PH is acidic, high PH is alkali.  Also silicon dioxide (ie. sand) is not acidic. Please edit your answer to make it clear and authoritative, adding references as appropriate.

Comment: @Rowyn Alloway Your edit has not substantially improved matters, lime does NOT lower PH.